# limitation of connected users on TFS

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

I am running TFS 2012 on a regular pc (windows 7),
and there are 4 developer pcs connected to that server.

I've noticed that sometimes I can't connect to TFS from my station (e.g when trying to check in files from VS2012).
When I try to connect from the same station using a different user - the connection is successful.

Just to clarify: this is not a prblem with the user itself - as it happens to all of the users in the system (sometimes the user can login, than for no apparent reason- he can't).

**I'm not running the free version of TFS (TFS Express)**, so I don't know why I get this user connections limitation. Could it be because I'm using windows 7 to run TFS and not windows server?

Comment: It shouldn't be a limitation of Win7.  What error message do you get when you try to connect?

Comment: TF31003: Either you have not entered the necessary credntials or your user acound does not have permission to connect to the team fondation server at...

Comment: Are you running on a domain? I've seen similar issues where a domain server isn't available intermittently...

Comment: yes, we are running on an internal domain. Any thoughts on how to fix this issue? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to come with when our domain server isn't available intermittently.
This is exactly what @Dan Puzey suggested - thank you Dan.

I'm posting this as an answer so it might help others to diagnose a similar situation.
The only solution I could find until now,
is to log off and log on again with the user.
Sometimes even restart the TFS SQL service is needed.
It would be nice if Microsoft solved this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The OS should impose no limits but IIS has limited concurrent connections based on the OS you're on.  See [here](http://www.jpelectron.com/sample/WWW%20and%20HTML/IIS-%20OS%20Version%20Limits.htm).

TFS does not impose any concurrent connection limits.  The standard edition on a client OS simply disallows binding Sharepoint and Reorting Services.  The free express version enforces that you use SQL Express and is for up to 5 users.

Also note that these are TCP connections and something like the TFS client could in some scenarios (like get) do multiple operations in parallel.  So it's not exact how many "concurrent" users you can get out of it. "A few" is what the config wizards say are appropriate for TFS on a client OS :)

From that link:

> **Windows 7 (IIS v7.5)2**
>
> - Starter:        No IIS
> - Home Basic:     No IIS Home
> - Premium:        simultaneous request execution limit of 3, allows multiple
>     sites
> - Business:       simultaneous request execution limit of 10, allows
>     multiple sites
> - Enterprise:     simultaneous request execution limit of
>     10, allows multiple sites
> - Ultimate:       simultaneous request execution
>     limit of 10, allows multiple sites

[Disclaimer I work on this so biased]

On a side note, you could try out TFS in the cloud which I believe last announcement was free for up to 5 users.  You also won't get any limitations, you have the option of git (coming to on-premise TFS in vNext).  That gives you the best of both worlds - no limits, 5 users, internet connected but git allows working disconnected.  My 2 cents ... http://tfs.visualstudio.com/

Comment: Thanks , it looks like a promising lead. I'm using the professional edition, I couldn't find it in the link, but I'm guessing 10 concurrent requests are supported. Do you know how could I confirm that this is the cause of my grief?

Comment: You could write a program to do multiple requests in parallel - write an asp.net page that takes some time to return ...

Comment: I believe Professional == Business.  You should probably have 10 concurrent but as I pointed out, a single user can consume multiple connections.

Comment: Actually this doesn't add up. if it were an issue of iis connection than if user A was unable to log in, then user B should also fail to connect, right? but in our system this happens all of the time (that user A fails but user B connects with no problems)

Comment: No, it's possible.  TFS makes http calls - being "connected" is just a client state.  It's possible to be connected and be tying up 0 IIS TCP sockets if you're not doing anything that invokes server calls.  Not saying this is definitely your problem but is possible for B to succeed after user A failed.

Comment: If this was the problem, then it would be most likely to occur when users overlap in concurrent server calls.  Easiest way to reproduce would be to have multiple users do a get of the full tree in a new workspace at the same time ( get creates multiple threads so 1 client can tie up multiple IIS sockets )

Comment: I have not been able to absolutely verify this, but it seems like you are right and it is related to IIS. I will try to switch to windows server. thank :)

Comment: while this was a promising lead, it is not the cause of my problems. (at least not the primary cause). I have been able to open a new web session with my browser to tfs, while the user in VS2012 is disconnected. so this is not related to IIS connection limit after all. thanks for the help